# Serialize [String:Any] to JSON

Tags: json, linux, swift

I'm trying out Swift on Linux.

I have data in the form of dictionaries with String keys, and values of Any type, and am trying to serialize these to a String in JSON format.

`NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` did not work, it complains 
`Argument type '[String : Any]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'`

```
let dict : [String : Any] = [
    "string" : "Hello",
    "int" : 1,
    "double" : 3.14,
    "array str" : ["a", "b", "c"],
    "array double" : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    "array int" : [1, 2, 3]
]
```

I know it must be doable, as the string representation of the dictionary is already almost in the right format:

```
print("\(dict)")
["array int": [1, 2, 3], "int": 1, "array double": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], "string": "Hello", "double": 3.1400000000000001, "array str": ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Before you suggest declaring dict as a `[String:AnyObject]`, the dictionary is filled from dynamic data, not declared as a literal.

If possible, I'd like to limit the use of OSX or iOS specific libraries that might not be available on the server.

**Edit:**

Here's an implementation of the solution proposed by Enrico Granata:

```
protocol JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> String?
}

extension String : JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> String? {
        return "\"\(self)\""
    }
}

extension Int : JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> String? {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

extension Double : JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> String? {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

extension Array : JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> String? {
        var out : [String] = []
        for element in self {
            if let json_element = element as? JSONSerializable, let string = json_element.toJSON() {
                out.append(string)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return "[\(out.joinWithSeparator(", "))]"
    } 
}

extension Dictionary : JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> String? {
        var out : [String] = []
        for (k, v) in self {
            if let json_element = v as? JSONSerializable, let string = json_element.toJSON() {
                out.append("\"\(k)\": \(string)")
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return "{\(out.joinWithSeparator(", "))}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, why does your use of dynamic data mean you can't use a dictionary that maps from strings to objects?

Comment: Because of `error: value of type 'Double' does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'`

Comment: Sadly I think what you're dealing with is one of Swift's ugly protruding Objective-C edges — it has no problems with collections containing reference types but Objective-C doesn't do reference types (semantically, anyway) and `NSJSONSerialization` is probably still Objective-C code. I don't want to have to advise that you switch to `AnyObject` and wrap your values as `NSNumber`s because that's not the sort of ugliness you should have to resort to in Swift. So hopefully somebody has a better solution than that. I'll open a playground and have a quick go myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there will be a few errors in the way I phrase this, since it's a tricky topic, but bear with me.

NSJSONSerialization is a Foundation API, not a Swift standard library one. As such, it comes from Objective-C on Darwin even though it has probably been reimplemented on Linux. The original API, again, is an Objective-C API which on OS X gets bridged over to Swift.

The bridging happens in terms of reference types (AnyObject). In Objective-C, that's quite good enough since all things that are Objective-C objects are reference types that can be referenced as one common type (id, or in Swift, AnyObject). On the pure Swift side, there are types that are not reference types (Array, Dictionary, Int, String, ...). All of those can be described, as you seem to know already, as confirming to a magic protocol named Any. Any is really just a type alias for protocol<>, but compiler magic exists around it.

For compatibility with its stock Darwin version, Foundation's NSJSONSerialization likes to talk in terms of AnyObject, not in terms of Any. As such, there exist types that it can't serialize.

I can see a few avenues:

a) you could exploit the Bridgeable protocol to try and go from [String: Any] to [String: X where X: Bridgeable] (not real syntax)

If you look at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSArray.swift, you'll see that Foundation adds:

```
extension Array : Bridgeable {
    public func bridge() -> NSArray { return _nsObject }
}
```

You should be able to use this to traverse your object graph and obtain an NS* version of your pure Swift objects, that would then be OK to pass to NSJSONSerialization. Your mileage may of course vary since not everything is necessarily losslessly bridgeable.

b) you could write your own JSON serializer that can deal with native Swift types

If you go down this path, you stop caring about Any or AnyObject or whatnot. Quite simply, you'd do something like

```
protocol JSONSerializable { func toJSON() -> String? }
```

and then for an Array,

```
extension Array : JSONSerializable { func toJSON() -> String? {
  out = "["
  for element in self { if let json_element = element as? JSONSerializable {
    if let string = json_element.toJSON() { out = out + string } else { return nil }
  }
  out = out + "]"
  return out
}
}
```

To be noted, that this code (a) is not a complete implementation as-is, (b) is also not necessarily the smartest most efficient way. Consider it a hint in the direction of what you would need to do. If you go down this road, you lose some code reuse, and have to worry about whatever quirks the JSON syntax has, but on the other hand, you get pretty much complete control over the serialization process, and you can stop worrying about Any.

Comment: As I'm not sure what a) means, I tried b), but again get stuck on the question what is or isn't an Any type: let a = [1, [2, 3, 4], 5]; if let val = a[1] as? [Any] .... it seems an Array<Int> is not an Array<Any>

Comment: see my edits - approach b) has nothing to do with your attempted cast.

Comment: I came to swift without a background in obj-c. I accepted your answer because I found it informative. I ended up writing my own serializer, with a very different approach, where I did have to worry about types. I will try yours as well, because it looks potentially more elegant and much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 3.0 Preview 3, you can just do:

```
JSONSerialization.data( withJSONObject: dict.bridge() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't like to hear it, `[String: AnyObject]` is the way to go. And I don't see any disadvantage with it. It nicely covers all the data types that are serializable to JSON. And it can easily be filled dynamically.

Tested in XCode Playground:

```
let dict : [String : AnyObject] = [
    "string" : "Hello",
    "int" : 1,
    "double" : 3.14,
    "array str" : ["a", "b", "c"],
    "array double" : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    "array int" : [1, 2, 3]
]

let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: [.PrettyPrinted])
let x = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print(x)
```

Output:

```
{
  "array double" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "array str" : [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ],
  "int" : 1,
  "array int" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "string" : "Hello",
  "double" : 3.14
}
```

Comment: If you import Foundation, a dictionary literal wraps values in in AnyObject compatible types, such as NSNumber. That only seems to work at compile time, and only on osx/ios, not in the Linux implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a typealias and use that:

```
#if os(Linux)
typealias JsonDict = [String: Any]
#else
typealias JsonDict = [String: AnyObject]
#endif
let dict : JsonDict = [
    "string" : "Hello",
    "int" : 1,
    "double" : 3.14,
    "array str" : ["a", "b", "c"],
    "array double" : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    "array int" : [1, 2, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to handle this on Linux (which is much stricter in its type casting), you'll need something closer to the following. Note the any conversion function. I've tested this on a hosted linux server. Also, I've added support here for casting of SwiftyJSON dictionaries. The SwiftyJSON package needs a little work to be excepted on Linux (specifically in removing NSErrorPointer from the initializer), and to work with this its rawDictionary needs to be made public. Feel free to ignore that part if you only care about the Serializer.

SwiftyJSON extension

```
import SwiftyJSON

extension JSON {
  public func hackyRawString() -> String? {
    switch self.type {
    case .dictionary:
      let string = self.rawDictionary.toJSON()
      return string
    default:
      return self.rawString()
    }
  }
}
```

Base JSONSerializer:

```
public protocol JSONSerializable {
  func toJSON() -> String?
  func anyConv(_ body: Any) -> String?
}

extension JSONSerializable {
  public func anyConv(_ element: Any) -> String? {
    if let json_element = element as? JSONSerializable, let string = json_element.toJSON() {
      return string
    } else if let json_element = Int("\(element)") as? JSONSerializable, let string = json_element.toJSON() {
      return string
    } else if let json_element = Bool("\(element)") as? JSONSerializable, let string = json_element.toJSON() {
      return string
    } else if let json_element = Double("\(element)") as? JSONSerializable, let string = json_element.toJSON() {
      return string
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
extension String : JSONSerializable {
  public func toJSON() -> String? {
    return "\"\(self)\""
  }
}

extension Int : JSONSerializable {
  public func toJSON() -> String? {
    return "\(self)"
  }
}

extension Double : JSONSerializable {
  public func toJSON() -> String? {
    return "\(self)"
  }
}

extension Bool : JSONSerializable {
  public func toJSON() -> String? {
    return "\(self)"
  }
}

extension Array : JSONSerializable {
  public func toJSON() -> String? {
    var out : [String] = []
    for element in self {
      if let string = anyConv(element) {
        out.append(string)
      } else {
        out.append("null")
      }
    }
    return "[\(out.joined(separator: ", "))]"
  }
}

extension Dictionary : JSONSerializable {
  public func toJSON() -> String? {
    var out : [String] = []
    for (k, v) in self {
      if let string = anyConv(v) {
        out.append("\"\(k)\": \(string)")
      } else {
        out.append("\"\(k)\": null")
      }
    }
    return "{\(out.joined(separator: ", "))}"
  }
}
```